# Laravel access csrf_token() in public folder path

Tags: laravel, token, csrf

I am using [*responsive File Manager*](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/) in my  project. i need to add CSRF token in its config file that is inside public folder. using `csrf_token()` in that config file doesn't work:

```
 $token = csrf_token();  //this is inside filemanager confing.php


 Fatal error: Call to undefined function csrf_token() in 
 E:\xampp\htdoc\site\public\plugin\filemanager\config\config.php on line 7
```

so how can i access this function in public folder?or totally access app instance out of Laravel typical pathes?

Comment: You problem actually resides at something else. Your plugin shouldn't be under public folder. You should probably use node to install https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to turn off csrf protection for that route, or add this code to header of page where that editor is enabled:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i have added csrf_token to config file manually . i need it to verify user

Comment: csrf_token is not for user verification. To verify user outside of Laravel: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-use-laravel-authuser-outside-laravel-and-pass-data-in-custom-php